# Missing argument 2 for wpdb prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Please help me with this.

I got this error:

> Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

For this line:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT name, term_id
                                             FROM wp_categoryindex
                                             WHERE alpha IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')"));
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Take a look at these: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks and http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using both functions `get_results()` and `prepare()`? Do you have idea about any of these functions?

I think this may be useful for you. Can you please try this:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name, term_id
                                             FROM wp_categoryindex
                                             WHERE alpha IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')");
```

Or

```
$myrows = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT name, term_id
                                             FROM wp_categoryindex
                                             WHERE alpha IN %s", "('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')");
$getData = $wpdb->get_var($myrows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a quick [RT*M](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) one finds that your missing second argument pointed out by the system should be parameters supporting `sprint()-like` placeholders, which you don't have. So you need to look over the documentation for the method and consider whether you wish to use the substitution capabilities or use a different method that doesn't require those, e.g, [query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/).

Parameters

- $query
  (string) (Required) Query statement with sprintf()-like placeholders
- $args
  (array|mixed) (Required) The array of variables to substitute into the query's placeholders if being called like http://php.net/vsprintf vsprintf(), or the first variable to substitute into the query's placeholders if being called like http://php.net/sprintf sprintf().
- $args,...
  (mixed) (Required) further variables to substitute into the query's placeholders if being called like http://php.net/sprintf sprintf().